# How to fix error "drush - command not found" for drupal8?

Tags: drush

I Installed drush8 via composer for drupal 8. I have updated `.bashsrc` file with `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`. But still when I try to execute drush command, terminal is showing "command not found"

Comment: Did you source your bashrc again so that the changes apply to your current terminal session?

Comment: Drupal 8.4+ requires Drush 9, see https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/#drupal-compatibility

Comment: And `Drush only supports one install method. It requires that your Drupal site be built with Composer and Drush be listed as a dependency.`

Comment: You have to run the command `source ~/.bashrc`, then the changes in bashrc files will be reflected.

Comment: @leymannx i installed drush 9, but it showed compatbility error, so i changed it to version 8

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa yes i ran the command `source ~/.bashrc`.. im wondering whether the path given is correct or not. `which $SHELL` gives me **\bin\bash**  and `echo $PATH` gives me **$HOME/usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/bin**

Answer (score 0):

Try this, If Drush already installed check using $which drush This will show you the current drush path something like ~/vendor/drush/drush

If you don't have drush installed you can add using
$ composer global require drush/drush

Add path to your .bashrc file.
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/home/currentusername/vendor/drush/drush

Export PATH

save you changes and exit the terminal and relogin to validate your drush works from anypath.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"

source ~/.bashrc
```